# Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level Apache tomcat, How do I keep getting these?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, logging

I'm running tomcat 6, and I get a warning ONCE, follow with that note,

Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level,

But they aren't logged anywhere, or at least I can't find them. But what I really want is for  all the occurences to keep showing in my log, because when I try to recreate the warning, well, they aren't showing anymore.

I have in my loggging.properties the next line:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
```

which is supposed to log everything, and I have also tried ALL and I still get the warning only ONCE.

What do I need to change so the warning shows everytime?